# TagSet for symbol inside NumericQ behaves differently than in other fooQ functions

Tags: expression-test, upvalues

I am trying to define some symbols as being numeric by using TagSet and encountered the following different behaviors between `NumericQ` and *e.g.* `IntegerQ`.

`TagSet` with `IntegerQ`, together with other built-in functions I've tried, also works when the symbol takes an argument.

```
f/:IntegerQ[f[_]]=True;
IntegerQ[f]
IntegerQ[f[1]]
(* ==>
False
True
*)
```

However, while trying to do the same with `NumericQ` it does not work.

```
g/:NumericQ[g[_]]=True;
NumericQ[g]
NumericQ[g[1]]
(* ==>
False
False
*)
```

Note though that `h/:NumericQ[h]=True; NumericQ[h]` gives `True` as expected.

Furthermore, `Definition` gives different output when applied to `f` compared to  `g, h` above:

```
Definition[f]
Definition[g]
Definition[h]
(* ==>
IntegerQ[f[_]]^=True
Null
Null
*)
```

This is very puzzling to me. Why is there this difference?

Comment: Consider using `SetAttributes[g, NumericFunction]` instead.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks a lot! Although it doesn't answer the question, it does solve my underlying problem. That ought to be more important but it's hard to let go of a puzzle once you started wonder... :-) Note also that it makes both `NumericQ[g]` and `NumericQ[g[1]]` evaluate to `True` and does not offer the flexibility of leaving `NumericQ[q]` as `False`, should one ever want that... I don't but worth mentioning for sake of generality. :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`...Set...` functions are overridden for `NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NumericQ/set.html). That's why your assignment `g /: NumericQ[g[_]] = True` does not work as expected.

I guess that the fact that above assignment doesn't complain with an error message, and just does nothing, might be considered a bug.

---

You could try to manually add necessary [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) to your `g`:

```
g // ClearAll
g // UpValues = {HoldPattern@NumericQ@g@_ :> True};
```

This will work when `NumericQ` is called directly on `g[...]`.

```
NumericQ@g       (* False *)
NumericQ@g[1]    (* True *)
NumericQ@g[1, 2] (* False *)
```

But it will not work when `g[...]` is deeper in some other expression:

```
NumericQ@Sin@g[1] (* False *)
```

---

For `NumericQ` to recognize `g[...]` with numeric arguments arbitrarily deep inside other numeric functions you could set [NumericFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericFunction.html) attribute (as suggested in [comment by J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153929/14303#comment410925_153929)), but this does not give you precise control on pattern for which `g[...]` will be considered numeric:

```
g // ClearAll
g // Attributes = NumericFunction;

NumericQ@g            (* False *)
NumericQ@g[a]         (* False *)
NumericQ@g[1]         (* True *)
NumericQ@g[1, 2]      (* True *)
NumericQ@Sin@g[1, Pi] (* True *)
```

---

Overridden assignments involving `NumericQ` allow defining custom symbols representing numerical constants like `E`, or `Pi`, in a way that *Mathematica* will recognize them as numerical. E.g:

```
NumericQ@Sin@myNumConst     (* False *)
NumericQ@myNumConst = True;
NumericQ@Sin@myNumConst     (* True *)
NumericQ@myNumConst = False;
NumericQ@Sin@myNumConst     (* False *)
```

You can also force *Mathematica* to forget that a built-in constant is numerical:

```
NumericQ@Sin@E      (* True *)
NumericQ@E = False;
NumericQ@Sin@E      (* False *)
```

*Mathematica* seems to store some internal collection of such numerical symbols since results of such assignments are not visible neither in `` Language`ExtendedDefinition@NumericQ `` nor in `` Language`ExtendedDefinition@myNumConst ``. Unfortunately I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Thank you for an illuminating and *almost* complete answer! Gotta love this forum! :-D The only remaining strange part is why `h/: NumericQ[h]=True` works fine (as expected) but yet doesn't show up in `Definition[h]`.

Comment: @Stalpotaten Effects of this assignment are neither in ``Language`ExtendedDefinition@h`` nor in ``Language`ExtendedDefinition@NumericQ``, there must be some internal collection of symbols for which `NumericQ` gives `True`, like `E`, or `Pi`. Overridden assignments involving `NumericQ` probably add symbols directly to that collection. Unfortunately I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that is as far as we get in this mystery, but it's far enough for me!

Comment: For constants, you can do `SetAttributes[myNumConst, Constant]` @Stalpotaten.