# Defining a function which is numerical on all vectors of arguments

Tags: functions, programming, attributes

There is an attribute `NumericFunction` in Mathematica that can do the following job:

```
Attributes[f] = {NumericFunction};
NumericQ[f[1,2,3,4]]
```

then returns true. However, the following return false

```
NumericQ[f[{1,2,3,4}]]; NumericQ[f[1,{2},3,{4}]]
```

which makes sense by Documentation on `NumericFunction`. However, I want to define a function $f$ that returns True even in above cases, how can this be achieved?

Curiously, functions like `HypergeometricPFQ` has Attributes `NumericFunction`, but `NumericQ[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, Sqrt[2]}, {Pi}, 1/3]]` still returns true despite having lists in its arguments, why?

My goal is to define an `f` such that all expressions like `f[1,{2},3,{4}]`, `1+5*f[1,{2},3,{4}]`, `Sin[1+5*f[1,{2},3,{4}]]` returns true upon `NumericQ`. How can this be done?

Thank you.

---

***Update:*** After much thoughts, I think I found a solution:

```
SetAttributes[f, NumericFunction]; Unprotect[NumericQ];
$numericflag = 0; 
NumericQ[expr_] /; FreeQ[expr, f] == False && $numericflag == 0 := 
 Block[{bool}, $numericflag = 1; 
  bool = NumericQ[expr /. f[x__] :> f @@ Flatten[{x}]]; $numericflag =
    0; Return[bool]]; Protect[NumericQ];
```

it works as expected: `NumericQ[Pi + 58 + f[2, 3, {4, 4}]]`, `NumericQ[Sin[f[2,{3,{0,0}}]]]` all return true.

Comment: I don't have a rigorous answer, but it appears that it is linked to the fact f is not defined. If you define f (e.g. ```f[l___]:=1``` the result of ```NumericQ@f[{1},2,3]``` become ```True```

Comment: @youyou Isn't it because `f` evaluates to `1` first?  `NumericQ` doesn't have any `Hold*` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought @swish would incorporate my comment, but let me put it here, since it is an answer to the question.  In the following, the arguments of `f` can be numbers or any sort of nested lists of numbers.

```
f /: NumericQ[f[args___]] /; VectorQ[Flatten@{args}, NumericQ] := True;

NumericQ[f[1, 2, 3, 4]]
NumericQ[f[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]
NumericQ[f[1, {2}, 3, {4}]]
NumericQ[f[x]]  (* False -- should check both cases T, F *)
NumericQ[f[]]   (* True  -- same as `NumericQ[Sin[]]` *)
(*
  True
  True
  True
  False
  True
*)
```

---

*Update*

@pisco points out that the above does not work if `f[..]` is nested inside other numeric expressions.  There is an internal function that could be used to replace `NumericQ`:

```
ClearAll[f];
Attributes@f = {NumericFunction};

Internal`WouldBeNumericQ[2 + f[1, {2}, 3], {}]
(*  True  *)
```

The last list is a list a variables, the function tests whether `f` would be numeric if numeric values were substituted for the variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, one major shortcoming seems that `NumericQ[1+f[1,2,3]]` returns false. If one sets `NumericFunction` attributes to `f`, this returns true. However, `NumericQ[1+f[1,{2},3]]` still returns false. How to tackle this?

Comment: @pisco I added a workaround to my answer.  Feel free to unaccept if it's not satisfactory.  The workings of `NumericQ` are hidden from `Trace`.  I suspect there are some optimizations in C that get around my first def.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight [problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153929/tagset-for-symbol-inside-numericq-behaves-differently-than-in-other-fooq-functio/153941#153941) with `NumericQ`, that prevents one to define your `UpValues` with it. So that would not work as expected:

```
f /: NumericQ[_f] := True
```

But manually

```
UpValues[f] = {HoldPattern[NumericQ[_f]] :> True};
```

it works as expected:

```
NumericQ[f[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]
NumericQ[f[1, {2}, 3, {4}]]
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: I think the solution is a little over-eager :) -- Try `NumericQ[f[1, {2, t}, 4]]` which should return `False`.  I think the def. `f /: NumericQ[f[args___]] /; VectorQ[Flatten@{args}, NumericQ] := True` is more on-target.